# SQL SELECT rows based on IFs and combination

Tags: sql

I have the following table in SQL:

```
| ID | USER_FK | ROLE_FK |
|----|---------|---------|
| 1  | 1       | 1       |
| 2  | 1       | 2       |
| 3  | 2       | 2       |
| 4  | 2       | 2       |
| 5  | 3       | 2       |
```

And from it I need to select the `USER_FK`s that has one or more rows with `ROLE_FK = 2`.
However I do not want to select the `USER_FK` that has at least one other `ROLE_FK` than just `2`.

So, selecting any `USER_FK` that ONLY has `ROLE_FK = 2`, in one or several rows. In above example, I would like `USER_FK = 2` and `USER_FK = 3` to be included in the results, but not `USER_FK = 1` (since it has one occurence of `ROLE_FK = 1`). How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user_fk
from t
group by user_fk
having min(role_fk) = max(role_fk) and min(role_fk) = 2;
```

If the minimum equals the maximum, then all the roles are the same.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed! And to build on, say that I would like the exact same for another ROLE_FK in the same results. I would like all users that has only 2 AND/OR 5 in role_fk. Could I simply add 

OR having min(role_fk) = max(role_fk) and min(role_fk) = 5